# Check my proof: sequence in $W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R}^N)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, inequality, solution-verification

Let $N\geq 1$, $1<p<N$ and consider $X:=W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R}^N)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Let $(u_n)_n\subset X$ be a sequence such that
$$|u_n|_{\infty}\leq M\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N},$$
where $M>0$ is a constant and $|\cdot|_{\infty}$ is the $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$-norm.

Consider the integral

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |u_n|^{\frac{p(p-2)}{p-1}} dx.$$
In these hypotheses, I am trying to understnd if my below argument holds true. In particular, I am interested in obtaining something which involves $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u_n|^p dx$ instead of $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |u_n|^{\frac{p(p-2)}{p-1}} dx.$

To this aim, I proceed in this way
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |u_n|^{\frac{p(p-2)}{p-1}} dx\leq|u_n|_{\infty}^{-\frac{p}{p-1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |u_n|^{p} dx\leq M\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u_n|^p dx.$$

Does my argument hold true? If not, could anyone please explain me why?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks fine. Should it be: $...\leq M^{-\frac{p}{p-1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u_n|^pdx$?

Comment: This looks suspicious. If you end up with an estimate containing a large constant (M) with a negative exponent, then most of the time something is wrong. Such an estimate would be too good to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is wrong. You seem to use that $|u|\le M$ implies
$$
|u|^{-\frac p{p-1}} \le M^{-\frac p{p-1}},
$$
which is clearly wrong as the exponent is negative.

I also doubt the claim is true at all. Maybe one can construct a counterexample of the form
$$
u(x) = \min(1, |x|)^s
$$
with $s<0$ such that $u\in W^{1,p}$ but not in $L^{\frac{p(p-2)}{p-1}}$.

Comment: You are definitely right, I think we all did not consider the minus sign!